# Why is my Python Tuple only storing first value?

Tags: python, mysql, tuples

I am storing a mysql query w/in a tuple in my python script. I have a raw_input variable w/in the script which I would like to check if their is a match w/in the tuple.

```
curs.execute("""SELECT username, id FROM employees WHERE gid!=4""")
rows=curs.fetchall()
db.close()

uname = raw_input('Type the username for the new device: ')

for row in rows:
  user = row[0]
  empid = row[1]

  if user == uname:
    print 'User ' + uname + ' found...'
  else:
    print 'Not Found'
```

This only works if I type the username of the first employee.  Any other employee returns 'Not Found'

I noticed that if I remove the raw_input line, and the if statement and add

```
for row in rows:
  user = row[0]
  empid = row[1]
  print user
```

It prints all of the values

Comment: Do you have a `return` or `break` following your `if-else` block? Also, are you certain your query is returning multiple records?

Comment: @idjaw - `curs.fetchall()` returns a list of tuples.

Comment: @Nicarus doh..right!

Comment: I have a break after the else statement.  I am positive the query is correct and returns multiple records when run through phpmyadmin

Comment: Your `break` is the problem because it is still within the `for` loop. Take it out and try again

Comment: I removed the break and it is working.  Thank you.  I am going to test your new code below and if it works, i will mark that as the answer.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a better approach based on what I assume you are trying to do.

There is no reason for the loop in Python to search for the user when you can simply add that to your `WHERE` clause.

```
# Get the username from input
uname = raw_input('Type the username for the new device: ')

# Check to see if username in table
curs.execute("SELECT username, id FROM employees WHERE gid != 4 AND LOWER(username) = %s", (uname.lower(),))
row = curs.fetchone() # If no records found, should return an empty tuple
db.close()

# Return the user if found
if row:
    user = row[0]
    empid = row[1]
    print 'User ' + user + ' found...'
else
    print 'Not Found'
```

This will return the username, if found. Otherwise 'Not Found'.

Comment: This looks great, I will test this when I return and mark it as the answer if it works.  Thanks so much for helping me!

Comment: this works Excellent!! @Nicarus thank you for helping me and supplying me with the new code

Comment: @craisondigital - Happy to help.